# Как скачать файл из интернета Java

Tags: java

Имеется ссылка вида https://..../dnld.php?t=125552. При вставке в адресную строку браузера скачивается файл. Пытался качать с помощью jsoup и apache.commons-io, качается просто, я как понимаю, код этого dnld.php или просто html страница. Возможно нужно сделать правильный запрос? Я не особо разбираюсь в вебе и тем более в php. Как мне скачать файл?

Comment: В голову приходят два варианта почему может не скачиваться файл. 1. Само скачивание стартует с данной страницы силами JS. Соответственно, вам надо будет либо каким-то образом выполнить JS со страницы, либо изучить его и, выдернув нужные данные из JS, сформировать итоговый запрос. 2. Веб-сервер по заголовкам запроса (наиболее вероятно - по User-Agent) выявляет, что запрос сформирован не из браузера. В этом случае нужно "замаскировать" свой запрос под браузерный.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться